# Jquery 1.3.2 error on Internet Explorer. Incompatibility, or error in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

For a site I'm building, I import my Jquery code from...

`http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js`

...but when I run the site in IE, it gives me various instances of "argument not valid" on line 4031.

This happens when I hover above a field which should be animated on trough Jquery. Here is the JS code I wrote...

```
$('body ul li').each(
        function(){
            var tamcompleto = $(this).css('height');
            $(this).hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).stop().animate({height:tamcompleto},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
                }
            );
            $(this).css('height','50px');
        }
    );
```

Is this a case of incompatibility? Or is my code wrong?

Also, I've tried `height:'auto'` instead of `height:'tamcompleto'` on the hover function, but it doesn't work, Isn't `height:'auto'` supposed to be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element doesn't have a height specified, `css('height')` won't return anything. You can use the `height` function instead, which gives you the actual height in pixels:

```
var tamcompleto = $(this).height() + 'px';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. On IE the dots for the <li> still show up, is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: @serv-bot: have a look at the *list-style* css property or ask a separate question.